# Logarithm of an applied permutation

Tags: combinatorics, logarithms, permutations

Say I have a cyclic permutation $P$, a known input $x$, and a known output $y$ such that

$$y = P^a x$$

for some $a$.  Is there a good way to search for $a$ (i.e. better than brute force)?  Are some families of permutations easier to work this out for?

I'm ideally looking for a solution that would work when the elements of $x$ and $y$ are not distinct (e.g. there are duplicate entries).

My current thought is to represent the permutation as a matrix, diagonalise, and then try viewing the multiplications as additions to the phase.  Not quite sure where that would lead me, though.